# hide all usercontrol and show only one usercontrol c#

Tags: c#, winforms, refactoring

I am trying to write some UI code in Winforms using Guna.UI framework. But in applying Hide() and Show() functions for multi controls I am struggled with having so much assignments for controls in void() function. How I can minimize the code and refactor it into proper structure?

Below is the example from my code:

```
 private void gunaButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboboxvivo.Text.Equals("Vivo V11 Pro")) V11Pro();

    }
    void V11Pro()
    {
        v11Pro1.Show();
        v11Pro1.BringToFront();
        testpointblank1.Hide();
        //vivohide//
        v91.Hide();
        v7Plus1.Hide();
        v71.Hide();
        y93Y951.Hide();
        y911.Hide();
        x231.Hide();
        //oppohide//
        a831.Hide();
        f91.Hide();
        f71.Hide();
        f51.Hide();
        rmX18311.Hide();
        rmX18311.Hide();
        //xiaomihide//
        redmi3x1.Hide();
        redmi5a1.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is your question here

Comment: sorry bro but my question is how to my codes became smaller theres to many hide(); codes sorry for my post i am freshman

Comment: Put them in an array or list, hide everything from there, show only one after maybe?

Comment: What UI framework is this?  Grouping the controls to be hidden into some kind of panel and then hiding the panel would probably be a clearer and more flexible approach, though the structure of your controls isn't provided.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes sir im using multi user control

Comment: @BACON im using guna ui

Comment: That's for WinForms?  What are the types of those fields you're hiding?  Are they all the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what Guna UI is (I'm impressed that there is something that doesn't have a StackOverflow tag).  But, assuming that all those controls inherit from some common base class, say `Control`, then you could do something like:

```
var controls = new List<Control>
{
    button1, button2, button3,    //etc.
};
controls.ForEach(c => c.Hide());
```

Not a whole lot more typing, but a little easier to maintain.